# Elasticsearch requirements to run on my server

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

So I am implementing search in my frontend and my backend . I found that most used search engines are algolia and elasticsearch. I decided to go with elasticsearch since it is open source and less costy but I am scared it would be a great overhead to my server if i decided not to host it on elastic cloud or aws or azure.

***My Question***: Will it be an overhead to my server or its load wont be much

Comment: of course, it would be an overhead and it would depend on the size of data you want to index in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch will run even with a 2GB ram, what you need to consider is what is the usage and how much data you planning to store and how you going to search them.
Better to have a try, setting up is very easy.